# Using linq to filter List of List

Tags: c#, linq

I still don't have a good grasp on LINQ yet, and felt like my code could be optimised so looking for help.

I have a Patient and Med Class, each have a public bool IsSelected.  These are wrapped into the PatientMeds and PatientsMeds Classes;

```
public class PatientMeds
{
    public Patient Patient;
    public List<Med> Meds;
}

public class PatientsMeds
{
    public List<PatientMeds> PatientMedsList;
}
```

I want to filter these, so if the Patient.IsSelected == false then ignore it, and ignore only the Meds where IsSelected == false;

Now, this code works:

```
List<PatientMeds> patientMedsList = PatientsMeds.PatientMedsList
    .Where(x => x.Patient.IsSelected)
    .ToList();
foreach (PatientMeds patientMeds in patientMedsList)
{
    var medsToRemove = patientMeds.Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected == false).ToList();
    foreach (Med med in medsToRemove)
    {
        patientMeds.Meds.Remove(med);
    }
}
```

But it just seems 'clunky'.  How can i make it better?

Comment: LINQ is for querying while your current code is actually modifying the `Meds` list of the existing `PatientMeds` objects. So how it should be?

Comment: You can use LINQ's Any method, for both requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
List<PatientMeds> patientMedsList = PatientsMeds.PatientMedsList
    .Where(x => x.Patient.IsSelected)
    .ToList();
patientMedsList.ForEach(p=> p.Meds.RemoveAll(m=>!m.IsSelected));
```

Comment: thanks. i didn't know that lambda syntax works with ForEach.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a new list with new `PatientMeds` instances containing only selected patients and meds:

```
var selectedPatientsWithSelectedMeds = patientMedsList.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                                      .Select(p => new PatientMeds
                                      {
                                        Patient = p.Patient,
                                        Meds = p.Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected).ToList()
                                      })
                                      .ToList();
```

So the `Where(p => p.IsSelected)` only selects selected patients, and the `Select(p => new PatientMeds { ... }` constructs new `PatientMeds` instances.

Finally `p.Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected).ToList()` constructs a new list with only selected meds.

But it's not clear whether constructing new `PatientMeds` and `List<Med>` instances is viable. For example at `new PatientMeds { ... }` you will need to map all properties of `PatientMeds`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `RemoveAll`

```
patientsMeds
    .PatientMedsList
    .Where(m => m.Patient.IsSelected)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(m => m.Meds.RemoveAll(med => !med.IsSelected));
```

As being reference type, despite you create new list using `ToList()` method, it will point to same location. So, the result also will be reflected at `patientsMeds` variable

Comment: None of the used methods are LINQ :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes, they are *linqish* methods of `List` calss :)

Comment: He wants to skip patients that `x.Patient.IsSelected == false`

Comment: @Valentin, `IsSelected` is property of `Med` calss seen from this code line: `...Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected == false)`. And my code does this.

Comment: @fubo, thanks for pointing. I haven't paid attention to that.

Comment: @fubo, it is what happens, when you hesitate to write answer . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try shortening the following foreach loop

```
foreach (PatientMeds patientMeds in patientMedsList)
{
    patientMeds.Meds.RemoveAll(m => m.IsSelected == false);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
var bb = patientMedsList.Where(p => p.Patient.IsSelected).ToList().Select(p => new PatientMeds { Patient = p.Patient, Meds = p.Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Comment: how does this filter unwanted meds?

Comment: OOPS, I missed that requirement. This should work "var bb = patientMedsList.Where(p => p.Patient.IsSelected).ToList().Select(p => new PatientMeds { Patient = p.Patient, Meds = p.Meds.Where(m => m.IsSelected).ToList() }).ToList();"